# Exporting a large Entity Framework Diagram

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, edmx

I have a fairly large Entity Diagram. I tried to export it to an image, unfortunately because it's so large the image comes out all pixelated.

See this link http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534574/edmx-model-image-export-pixelation for the error report (made by someone else).

So I was wondering is there another way to export that diagram.
I don't want to have to write my own exporting utility.

I tried using entity developer to open my model but it just crashed, and when I went to report the error their web site threw up an error so while I could try and fix what they are complaining about in my model, I don't trust their application enough to view it as a permanent solution and don't want to invest that time for a temporary one.

Ideally I would be able to export it into some other UML like diagram that people without Visual Studio can edit and return to me, but I'll settle for image export that is detailed enough for you to be able to read the names of the entities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

There's a simple way to achieve what you need.

Download a virtual printer like [PDF Creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/download).

Open the EDMX file.

Go to "File > Page Setup..." and choose a bigger Paper Size, "ARCH E3" is pretty good.

Go to "File > Print..." and select "PDF Creator" from the available printers and click "OK". PDF Creator options will be shown, input your desired file name and where it says "Profile" select the format you need like "JPEG" or "PNG", you can also export to "PDF" of course.

Now click "Save" and voilà.

Comment: Just to clarify... I couldn't find ARCH E3 under Visual Studio page setup.  I had to select PDFCreator as the printer -> Properties -> Advanced and choose it from there.

Answer (score 4):

Change the Printer to **Microsoft XPS Document Writer**. It will then be big enough to display, even if it won't fit on a standard piece of paper.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from visual studio
`File > Print` and then choose PDF and you image wont comes out all pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

You can export it to OneNote too.
File -> Print -> Send to OneNote

But dont use dark theme in your visual studio, because numbers in relations (like 0..1, *) are not visible.
You have to switch the theme to Light (Tools -> Options -> Envihiroment -> General)